# Excel Run-time Error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, range, unions

I am attempting to change borders that have been affected through the "Click and drag" copy method, with a 1 click fix macro that will only change the borders but not the data inside.
I used the create a Macro function and selected all the necessary cells and changed the border format.
The cell range will not change but I am getting an error after creating the macro. The only items when debugging that are highlighting is the union.
Code is below, any help would be wonderful

```
Sub B96A()
'
' B96A Macro
'

'
    Union(Range( _
        "N28:O29,N30:O31,N32:O33,N34:O35,N36:O37,N38:O39,N40:O41,N42:O43,P4:Q5,P6:Q7,P8:Q9,P10:Q11,P12:Q13,P14:Q15,P16:Q17,P18:Q19,P20:Q21,P22:Q23,P24:Q25,P26:Q27,P28:Q29,P30:Q31,P32:Q33,P34:Q35,P36:Q37,P38:Q39,P40:Q41,P42:Q43,R4:S5,R6:S7,R8:S9,R10:S11" _
        ), Range( _
        "R12:S13,R14:S15,R16:S17,R18:S19,R20:S21,R22:S23,R24:S25,R26:S27,R28:S29,R30:S31,R32:S33,R34:S35,R36:S37,R38:S39,R40:S41,R42:S43,T4:U5,T6:U7,T8:U9,T10:U11,T12:U13,T14:U15,T16:U17,T18:U19,T20:U21,T22:U23,T24:U25,T26:U27,T28:U29,T30:U31,T32:U33,T34:U35" _
        ), Range( _
        "T36:U37,T38:U39,T40:U41,T42:U43,V4:W5,V6:W7,V8:W9,V10:W11,V12:W13,V14:W15,V16:W17,V18:W19,V20:W21,V22:W23,V24:W25,V26:W27,V28:W29,V30:W31,V32:W33,V34:W35,V36:W37,V38:W39,V40:W41,V42:W43,X4:Y5,X6:Y7,X8:Y9,X10:Y11,X12:Y13,X14:Y15,X16:Y17,X18:Y19" _
        ), Range( _
        "X20:Y21,X22:Y23,X24:Y25,X26:Y27,X28:Y29,X30:Y31,X32:Y33,X34:Y35,X36:Y37,X38:Y39,X40:Y41,X42:Y43,Z4:AA5,Z6:AA7,Z8:AA9,Z10:AA11,Z12:AA13,Z14:AA15,Z16:AA17,Z18:AA19,Z20:AA21,Z22:AA23,Z24:AA25,Z26:AA27,Z28:AA29,Z30:AA31,Z32:AA33,Z34:AA35,Z36:AA37,Z38:AA39" _
        ), Range( _
        "AB4:AC5,AB6:AC7,AB8:AC9,AB10:AC11,AB12:AC13,AB14:AC15,AB16:AC17,AB18:AC19,AB20:AC21,AB22:AC23,AB24:AC25,AB26:AC27,AB28:AC29,AB30:AC31,AB32:AC33,AB34:AC35,AB36:AC37,AB38:AC39,AB40:AC41,AB42:AC43,AD4:AE5,AD6:AE7,AD8:AE9,AD10:AE11,AD12:AE13,AD14:AE15,AD16:AE17" _
        ), Range( _
        "AD28:AE29,AD30:AE31,AD32:AE33,AD34:AE35,AD36:AE37,AD38:AE39,AD40:AE41,AD42:AE43,AF4:AG5,AF6:AG7,AF8:AG9,AF10:AG11,AF12:AG13,AF14:AG15,AF16:AG17,AF18:AG19,AF20:AG21,AF22:AG23,AF24:AG25,AF26:AG27,AF28:AG29,AF30:AG31,AF32:AG33,AF34:AG35,AF36:AG37,AF38:AG39" _
        ), Range( _
        "AH12:AH13,AH14:AH15,AH16:AH17,AH18:AH19,AH20:AH21,AH22:AH23,AH24:AH25,AH26:AH27,AH28:AH29,AH30:AH31,AH32:AH33,AH34:AH35,AH36:AH37,AH38:AH39,AH40:AH41,AH42:AH43,L4:M5,L6:M7,L8:M9,L10:M11,L12:M13,L14:M15,L16:M17,L18:M19,L20:M21,L22:M23,L24:M25,L26:M27,L28:M29" _
        ), Range( _
        "L36:M37,L38:M39,L40:M41,L42:M43,N4:O5,N6:O7,N8:O9,N10:O11,N12:O13,N14:O15,N16:O17,N18:O19,N20:O21,N22:O23,N24:O25,N26:O27" _
        )).Select
    Range("AH42").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlDash
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlDash
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like a loop would be a much better approach than `Union` here.

Comment: There's a 255-character limit on a `Range` address. One of your references is longer than that. But a loop would be much better and would save you some typing too.

Comment: Due to the limit can I possible break it up into smaller macros to do the same thing and still keep the unions? I am not sure how to address a loop function.  I also would like to have this spread across multiple sheets.